# Sonarqube community plugin checks are not reported, although PR decoration via comments works

Tags: sonarqube

I've followed the setup instructions for the community plugin to the tee, and managed to get PRs visible in the Sonar UI, get bot-comments/reports in the right PRs, and was feeling fairly confident - until I noticed that there was a check being offered in the Github *required checks* type-ahead search, which I never saw reported.

How do I get SonarQube to also report Github checks, and why is it not working, when all the other PR-integration *is* working?

Since this feature is not documented for SonarQube 8.9, nor specifically mentioned in the plugin, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Abraham Berg's blog post](https://www.abrahamberg.com/blog/sonarqube-pull-request-scanner-community/) I was able to figure out the missing piece.

In addition to the documented pull-request specific parameters, you need to specify the branch-sha1 via

```
-Dsonar.scm.revision=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

in order for the checks API to be called correctly.

I assume the checks showed up on the repo, because they were being called, but Github was not able to map them to the right PR.